# Vector Poisson Equation for a symmetrical geometry

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, computational-physics

I was recently doing some simulations involving the vector Poisson equation and symmetrical geometries with respect to one plane. My question is basically if the computations involved can be reduced by exploiting the symmetry of such situations. The vector poisson equation is given by:

$$\nabla^2\vec{A}=\vec{J}\quad\forall\vec{x}\in\Omega$$

As a simple example of such a symmetrical geometry, consider the model of a transformer shown below: [image: FEM Simulation of a transformer]

Now it's clear that the quantities $\vec{B},\vec{H}$ are symmetric with respect to the plane spanned by $\vec{e}_x$ and $\vec{e}_z$ whereas the current density $\vec{J}$ is not.

Could we therefore reduce our problem to the domain $\Omega_{y>0}:=\{\vec{x}\in\Omega:\vec{x}(2)=y>0\}$ by restating our problem as:

$$\nabla^2\vec{A}=\vec{J}\quad\forall\vec{x}\in\Omega_{y>0}$$
$$(\mathrm{some\ boundary\ condition})$$

If yes, how could one define the missing boundary condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, basically after thinking some more about it, I was able to come up with a solution to this problem. The idea is to consider the three independent,scalar problems:

$$\nabla^2A_i=J_i\quad i\in\{1,2,3\}$$

It is clear that $A_z=0$ since $J_z=0$. Since $A_x$ is symmetric with respect to the plane $P_{x=0}$, one can get $A_{x}$ by solving the following PDE with Neumann boundary conditions and a reduced domain:

$$\nabla^2A_x=J_x \quad \forall \vec{x}\in\Omega_{x>0}$$
$$\nabla A_x\cdot\vec{n}=0 \quad \forall\vec{x}\in P_{x=0}$$

Since $A_y$ is symmetric with respect to the plane $P_{y=0}$, one can analogously compute $A_y$ by solving the following PDE with Neumann boundary conditions and a (different) reduced domain:

$$\nabla^2A_y=J_y \quad \forall \vec{x}\in\Omega_{y>0}$$
$$\nabla A_y\cdot\vec{n}=0 \quad \forall\vec{x}\in P_{y=0}$$

So the computational effort can be reduced by a factor of two by solving the PDEs on the reduced domains above and mirroring the results.